# npmでインストールしたパッケージをコマンドで実行する方法

Tags: npm

## 環境

- Windows10
- nodejs v8

#### やりたいこと

`redoc-cli`を使ってopenapi3で書かれたswagger.yamlからHTMLを生成したいです。
https://github.com/Rebilly/ReDoc/tree/master/cli

## 質問

Install方法には、以下のように書かれています。

> You can use redoc cli by installing redoc-cli globally or using npx.

私の環境のnodejsはv8なので、npxコマンドがインストールされていません。
したがって`npm istall redoc-cli`でインストールしました。

インストールした`redoc-cli`を、どのように実行すればよいでしょうか？

#### 分かっていること

インストールした`redoc-cli`は`%USERPROFILE%\node_modules`フォルダに存在するので、以下のコマンドで実行できることは分かりました。

```
node %USERPROFILE%\node_modules\redoc-cli\index.js
```

しかし何かが違うように思います。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`npm install redoc-cli` を実行した場合、パッケージは**ローカルインストール**され、**カレントディレクトリもしくは祖先の node_modules フォルダに配置**されます。

このコマンドにグローバルオプション ( `--global`, `-g` ) を付与すると、パッケージは**グローバルインストール**され、**環境変数に設定されたフォルダ内に配置**されます。これにより、グローバルインストールしたパッケージは、どのディレクトリでも使用することが出来るようになります。

---

質問文で引用している文章では、以下で太字にしたように、「**グローバルインストール**するか、 npx コマンドを使用する」方法を示しています。

そのため、今回質問者さんが実行するコマンドは `npm install redoc-cli` ではなく、 `npm install -g redoc-cli` ではないでしょうか？

> You can use redoc cli by installing redoc-cli **globally** or using npx.

---

もし、「ローカルインストールでパッケージを実行しなければならない」ということであれば、 npm scripts 経由で実行出来ます。`package.json` 内の script フィールドに redoc-cli コマンドを実行するスクリプトを記述し、 npm run コマンドで実行すると良いと思います。

Comment: >npm install -g redoc-cli ではないでしょうか？
失礼いたしました。確かglobalオプションを付けて一度インストールした覚えがあります。